# Value of max flow and min cut in a graph with no directed paths

Tags: graph-theory, network-flow

Let $N(x, y)$ be a network which contains no directed $(x, y)$-path.

How do I show that the value of a maximum flow and the capacity of a minimum cut in $N$ are both zero?

Answer (score 0):

Apply weak duality: maximum flow is at most minimum cut, so if you exhibit a flow and cut that have the same value, they are both optimal.

Comment: Why do they have the same value?

Comment: You need to construct a flow and cut that have the same value (in this case, zero).

Comment: I don't see how this proves my statement - would you mind writing out a more formal proof?